# Mapping AngularJs codes to ReactJs?

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, angularjs-rootscope

I'm new to reactjs. I want to know, is there an equivalent for angular services such as `$rootScop`, `$q`, `$webSocket` in reactJs?

**code**:

```
.service('a', function ($rootScope, $location, $q, $webSocket) {
    this.init = function () {
        b()
        c()
 }
```

For example code parameters above what equivalent in react? I know the equivalent `$scope` in react is `this.state`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as services in react

here are alternatives.

1. $rootscope --> state, you can share it across components. (You can use redux for state management whose philosophy is one true source of data).
2. $q --> Es6 Promise
3. $websocket --> html5 websocket.

Some thing similar to service is you can write a Class or Function which takes all the required services as params and you can call it any where by exporting it.

some similar implementation you can use for react.

In service.js

```
const myService = (...otherServices) => {
    doStuff1();
    doStuff2();
    return {
       ...items
    }
}
export default myService;
```

In component.js

you can import it

```
import myService from './service';
import React from 'react';
class testComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.data = myService().getData(); //just an example.
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>{this.data}</div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: `$http` => axios (https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios). There are others but this one will be familiar coming from `$http`.

Comment: These are just one alternative i can think of on top of my mind. there are many alternatives we can use and new ones keep coming.

Answer (score 0):

`$rootScope` -> it is an global scope object in angular, in react we use reducers  to store data which will be accessible to all components

`$q`-> we have q library same as `$q` in react

`$location` -> we have transition/history inside instance of class/components

`$webScocket`-> t
here are multiple modules https://blog.pusher.com/making-reactjs-realtime-with-websockets/

Comment: q library: Es6 Promise?  OR react-q ?

Comment: you can use react-q which is npm module which allow you to create your own promise/ allow synchronus programming